# scpを鍵認証で自動転送させたい。

Tags: php, linux, scp

質問します。
scpをphpでやりたいと思い、鍵認証で一部自動で転送されるんですが、
特定のサーバーだけ、パスワードをきいてきて自動転送が出来ない状態です。

私の分かる限りで/home/user_nameの下にssh-keygen・・・なんたらかんたら、みたいなので作成して、
その中のid_rsa.pubの公開鍵を、自動で転送したい、/home/user_name/.ssh/authorized_keysに手動で追加して、保存しましたが、まだパスワードを聞いてきます。

どこか抜けてますかね？？

Comment: scpまたはsshを-vオプションを付けて実行(ssh -v remotehost)した結果を、質問を編集して追記してください

Comment: 聞かれているのはSSH時のログイン先パスワードではなく、作成した公開鍵のパスワードではありませんか？

Answer (score 1):

真っ先に思いつくのは、サーバー側の sshd_config の設定で 鍵認証が有効化されてないという可能性です。設定ファイルを開いて、`PubkeyAuthentication yes` が有効になっているか確認してみてください。

パスワード無しでscp出来ているサーバーと設定ファイルを比較してみるのも良いかもしれません。